# iOS Game Center send json in match data

Tags: ios, game-center

I am trying to send JSON data in matchData object when a user end its turn. If I check the json before sending it is valid and looks like,

JSON:

```
{
  "p1score" : "0",
  "turn" : "0",
  "pb1" : "BPS1120|2231|3422|4213|5244|6135",
  "player2" : "0000177110",
  "player1" : "0000177110",
  "p2score" : "0",
  "movements" : "MVS2242",
  "pb2" : "BPS1630|2511|3522|4543|5534|6625",
  "moves" : "30"
}
```

Prepares the data for sending,

`NSData *matchData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",realMatchData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

`realMatchData` contains the above json string.

But if convert the `matchData` back to string again to check what is being sent using,

`NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:matchData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

I get back the following json string

```
{
  "moves" : "30",
  "turn" : "0",
  "player2" : "G:0000177110",
  "p1score" : "0",
  "player1" : "G:0000177110",
  "movements" : "MVS",
  "p2score" : "0"
}
```

keys `pb1` and `pb2` are missing.

I event tried to pass the values of `pb1` and `pb2` as nested json but problem remains the same, they keys are missing when sending data.

Is the right way to share the game state or should I use some other approach to share data ?

Thanks.

Comment: A wild guess: Did you try changing the encoding?

Comment: This doesn't look like its related to Game Center at all. I use `NSJSONSerialization` to pass JSON over Game Center as the match data with no issues at all, and I suspect that if you try just encoding and decoding your `NSString` in this manner without the intermediate step of transmitted it you will have the exact same issue.

Comment: @BenPious: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Thanks to all for helping, it was just an if condition that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question exactly, but it may solve the problem, and the asker asked for an example. Apple provides its own JSON serialization which produces an NSData object from JSON serializable objects like `NSNumber, NSArray, NSString, NSDictionary,` etc.

```
NSMutableArray* matchArray = [NSMutableArray array];

/*
   Fill the match array with the appropriate objects to represent your game state...
   You've presumably already done this in order to get that string object...
*/

NSData* matchData =  [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: matchArray 
                               options: 0 //pretty sure all the options here are irrelevant for our purposes
                                 error: NULL]; //pass in a pointer to an NSError if you are interested in the error

//end the turn or do whatever one does in a non-turn-based match with matchData as the data object
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but what I just find out that the data is not being set as it should due to some conditions. Still have to find the bug in my code.